# Local DNS resolve error in Azure while connecting resources in the vnets that are in peered

Tags: azure, api-gateway, azure-container-apps, azure-dns

We have api gateway in vnet-1 and container apps (backend pools) in vnet-2. these two vnets are peered with each other however we are facing Local-DNS resolve error when we try doing connectivity test from api gateway to container app.
Local Error: DNSResolution.

If we keep container app and api gateway in the same vnet it works fine.
Why the resources in peered vnet getting DNSResolution error ?

Comment: Thanks @Imran, I just got it working, we have to create a virtual network link in pvt DNS zone and then resources in that Vnet can access this private DNS zone.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer, We got it working by creating a virtual network link in pvt DNS zone and then resources in that Vnet can access this private DNS zone.
Read more about vnet links in private DNS zone here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-virtual-network-links